# Reading text files in Ada: Get_Line "reads" the byte-order mark as well

Tags: ada, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to read a file line-by-line in Ada, it's a XML text file. I'm following the instructions here:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Ada

However there's a problem that annoys me: the "Get_Line" function seems to be unaware of byte-order marks and reads them as part of the text itself, which means that when I raed the lines, the first one will always start with some extra bytes that should not be there.

While removing the extra bytes manually from the string is no big deal it seems strange to me that a function dedicated to text input/output is unaware of BOMs, there must be a way to read a text file in ada without having to worry about this... is there?

Comment: The Ada language (and libraries) by itself has no understanding of concepts like this.  That's really left up to the implementation (and remeHowever, when you open the file, there is a `Form` parameter that allows you to give it information about the file format.  The contents of this parameter depend on your particular Ada implementation, and you'll have to read their user manual.  First question: Did you use the `Form` parameter to tell it you were reading a UTF-8 file?  If not, it may be assuming the file is Latin-1.

Comment: @ajb: I'm using AdaCore's implementation (GNAT 2014). I tried passing a form string with the "encoding=utf8" parameter, but nothing changes. As for the language "not having any clue about these concepts"... to be honest I would expect a function from package "Text_IO" to know how a text file works. I've used lots of languages (C#, VB, c++/qt, Java...) and never had this problem to be honest. Fair enough if it's not detected by default, but there must be a way to exclude the BOMs reading other than cutting it out of the stream manually in code...

Comment: As a side note, only the very first character is considered a transparent BOM. When found later in the stream, BOMs are not expected to be removed automatically. This is since Unicode 4 or 5. Earlier versions of Unicode allowed for characters to eventually change mid-stream (UTF-16 in little endian could become UTF-16 big endian and vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ada.Text_IO` is specified to handle ISO-8859-1 encoded text, so ignoring an UTF-8 feature is the proper thing to do.

If `Ada.Wide_Text_IO` and `Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO` also output the byte-order-mark, when asked to read UTF-8 encoded text, then you should consider reporting it as a bug to GCC - but as there is quite a lot of implementation defined details for the text I/O packages in Ada, you should be ready for a "wont fix" answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using the stream attributes and making a `UTF_8` file-type to handle the BOM reading-and-discarding.